# Use index of current replacement with "Find and replace" functionallity in VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm wondering if there is a way to use the current found index in the replacement input field of visual studio code.

Example Text

```
<NotationType />
<NotationType />
<NotationType />
```

Find `<NotationType`  and replace all occurrences with `<NotationType id="q-CURRENTINDEX"`  to result in

```
<NotationType id="q-0" />
<NotationType id="q-1" />
<NotationType id="q-2" />
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the extension [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen) you can use the selection index as part of the replace text.

Make a Multi Cursor selection of what you want to find

1. Select `<NotationType />` or use a regex in the Find dialog
2. use menu option **Select** | **Select All Occurrences**

Execute command: `Generate text based on Regular Expression (regex)`

1. If needed fill in a regex to dissect the selected text of each selection
2. As Generator expression use: `<NotationType id="q-{{=i}}" />`

You get a preview of the replacement.

Use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept or <kbd>Escape</kbd> to cancel.

---

In this case it is simpler.

1. create the number of empty lines equal to the number of repetitions you want
2. put a multi cursor on each line with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>DownArrow</kbd>
3. Execute the command and use the same Generator Expression

Comment: thats kind of cool, thanks for this. too bad its a text-generation addon and not a search-and-replace one. Otherwise one could do more advanced stuff with it.

Comment: @choise I can add a `Find` input box to the command that will create a multi cursor selection based on a regex. What kind of advanced stuff can't you do right now? You can split the selected text more specific with the `Original text regex` to be used in the generate regex

Comment: aaah, then its totally fine. So i could use `Original text regex` to capture parts of the original selection and then use those values with `{{1}}`. Its just one more step. With default Find/Replace in VSCode the Find part finds all ocurrences based on a regex and you can also use capture groups there. With your addon i would have to write a regex to find the cursor selection, one to capture the selection and one to replace the selection. anyway, that still totally works for my usecase. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @choise You can use the `Find` regex also as the `Original text regex` if you have the same groups in both.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension to handle similar situations where you would like access to variables like match indices, line numbers, path variables, the clipboard, conditional replacements (like a snippet can do) and more: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview).

Your case is relatively straightforward, using this keybinding (or it could be a setting):

```
{
  "key": "alt+y",                      // whatever keybinding you want 
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "(NotationType)",
    "replace": "$1 id=\"q-${matchIndex}\"",
    // "restrictFind": "selections",         // if you need it
    "isRegex": true
  }
}
```

[image: replace with match index demo]